Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
I am a new user of Ubuntu and have version 22.04 lts.
every time I turn on the computer and use the internet using WIFI, chrome returns: ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE for most websites I try to access. I found a command on the internet that temporarily solves the problem and I can use it normally:
sudo dhclient -r wlp2s0
sudo dhclient wlp2s0

but restarting wlp2s0 solves it temporarily, I wanted to know if anyone knows what the problem is and how to solve it definitively.

It sounds like you have your wifi adapter set to manual ip, or some other setting.
You need to set your wifi adapter to use dhcp to obtain an ip address.  See the below image.

If this does not work, can you please post a copy a ipconfig -br a when the connection is not working, and one when it is working.
